# Can't create array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is a very weird problem.

I can't use array usong mongoose.

This is my User Schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
list_users_ticked: [String],
name : { type: String, required: true } ,
reg_id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }

});
```

This is how I try to use this schema for updating the user:

```
exports.update = function(cur_reg_id, user_ticked) {

    User.find({reg_id: cur_reg_id},function(err, users){

        if (err) throw err;

        var len = users.length;

        if(len == 0 || len > 1){

                callback({'response':"You didn't register"});

        } else {

            var usr = users[0];
            console.log(usr)
            usr.list_users_ticked.push("This line is returning the `error!!!!!");`
           // users[0].save(function(err) {
            //    if (err) throw err;

              ///  callback({'response':"User Saved   " + user_ticked});

          //  });


        }});



        //console.log('User successfully updated!');
}
```

This is how I login the user:

```
    exports.login = function(name, list_users_ticked, reg_id, callback) {

    var newuser = new User({
        name: name,
        list_users_ticked: list_users_ticked,
        reg_id: reg_id
    });

    User.find({reg_id: reg_id},function(err, users){

        var len = users.length;

        if(len == 0){
            newuser.save(function (err) {

                callback({'response':"Sucessfully Registered"});

            });
        }else{

            callback({'response':"User already Registered"});

        }});
}
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Someone have an idea for why it happened?

Comment: Try adding a default empty array in the schema.

Comment: I tried, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your database. Have you saved an item in the database prior to creating the array in your schema? If you have an item in there that doesn't have the field `list_users_ticked` you would see that error because it wouldn't exist to call push on.